# Were there Any Other Game/Sports World Cups organised besides Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter

Besides quidditch, The Wizards and Witches played some other games too, like Chess and Gobstones (that's what i think is the spelling, Saw it in HP5 game). So is there any fact of World Cups or even Inter House Tournaments being organised of other games/sports?

Answer (score 5):

### Gobstones has organised teams and tournaments, both professionally and at Hogwarts.

We first learned about this from the [first issue of the Daily Prophet](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/other-canon/dp/dp1) that JK Rowling had written for Bloomsbury's official Harry Potter fanclub, which included a letter that referenced the Welsh  National  Gobstones  Team and they're victory over Hungary.

> **GOBSTONES TOURNAMENT OVERLOOKED**
>   Dear Sir,
>   As a  member of  the  Welsh  National  Gobstones  Team  (...)  I  was surprised  to  see that  the Daily  Prophet  did  not  cover our resounding  triumph  (...)  I  was most  upset  to  learn that  our victory was  not  deemed  worthy of a single line  in  your paper.
>   --  Grugwyn  Rufford
>   **OUR EDITOR WRITES**
>   I  am sorry to  hear that  you  do  not  feel we  give enough  coverage  to  the game of  Gobstones.  The reason for this  is that  most wizards find  it  deeply  boring.

In book six we learn that Hogwarts had a Gobstones Team:

> The picture showed a skinny girl of around fifteen. She was not
>   pretty; she looked simultaneously cross and sullen, with heavy
>   brows and a long, pallid face. Underneath the photograph was the
>   caption: Eileen Prince, **Captain of the Hogwarts Gobstones
>   Team**.
>   (HBP25)

The [Pottermore article on Gobstones](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gobstones) goes on to mention The National Gobstone Association.

> **Professional Gobstone players compete in national leagues and international tournaments**, but it remains a minority sport within the wizarding world, and does not enjoy a very 'cool' reputation, something its devotees tend to resent. Gobstones is most popular among very young wizards and witches, but they generally 'grow out' of the game, becoming more interested in Quidditch as they grow older. **The National Gobstone Association** has attempted recruitment campaigns such as 'Give Gobstones A Second Glance', although the choice of accompanying picture (current Gobstones World Champion Kevin Hopwood being squirted with an eyeful of gunk) was perhaps ill-chosen.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, there are professional competitions for other sports.**

But Quidditch is by far the most popular and well-respected. Some examples:

- Quoting [from the Pottermore article](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Gobstones) about Gobstones:

  > **Professional Gobstone players compete in national leagues and international tournaments**, but it remains a minority sport within the wizarding world, and does not enjoy a very 'cool' reputation, something its devotees tend to resent.
- Possibly a tongue-in-cheek reference to the state of real-world US sports (which often differ from their international counterparts), *Quidditch Through the Ages*  mentions a rival sport named “Quodpot”:

  > The United States has not produced as many world-class Quidditch teams as other nations because the game has had to compete with the American broom game Quodpot. […] Quodpot has had some success as a minority sport in Europe, though the vast majority of wizards remain faithful to Quidditch.

  It seems likely that there are national tournaments for Quodpot, and that there are Quodpot competitions at the American school of magic (the name and structure of which is as yet unknown).
- Moving quite far the canon stack, Harry also meets Chess champions from the different houses in the *Order of the Phoenix* game – there must be some sort of inter-house tournament. Although given Ron’s skill in the game, it’s a little surprising that he never seems to be invited to take part.

Answer (score 3):

There are many sports and games in the wizarding world besides Quidditch, however, it is the most popular.

**Games**

There are a few games in the wizarding world, that have been mentioned throughout the series. They include [Exploding Snap](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Exploding_Snap), [Gobstones](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gobstones), and [Wizard's Chess](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard's_Chess).

**Sports**

I assume that this is what you are looking for, as you mentioned Quidditch. I've just added the former as you included "Games" in your title.

Many games are found within the Harry Potter series, such as [Quodpot](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quodpot), [Aingingein](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Aingingein), [Creaothceann](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Creaothceann), [Shuntbumps](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Shuntbumps), [Stichstock](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stichstock), [Swivenhodge](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Swivenhodge), Wizards' Duel, and Headless Hunt sports.

Comment: This seems to entirely miss the point of the question, which is regarding organized competition in these sports, not the existence of the sports themselves.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yeah, the existence of sport is previously asked... that's where I got the idea of organised sports... thanks :)

Comment: @prakharlondhe Hm, that has eluded me. I apologize. I may update at a later date.

Comment: @Jake No need to apologize, misunderstanding can happen to anyone and anytime.... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Most likely**

There are other games, clubs, and organization for games but Quidditch is the most popular. We learn one of the possible candidates for Beater on Angelina's team said that if it interfered with his/her's (can't remember) gobstones team they wouldn't play. We also learn that Snape's mom was the head of some sort of team in the newspaper. I don't think there is a direct canon, but I find it most likely there are official and international World Cups for these groups.